# Aggregate Total with Highcharts Line Chart

Tags: highcharts

I'm making a line graph with numeric values, and the customer would like a line that shows the Total.  I tried adding a data series called "Total", and while that works, it alphabetizes "Total" in with the data.  And I'd really like if the total were somehow differentiated from the other values, such as being a thicker line.

Is such a thing built into HighCharts?  If not, any better suggestions on how to add a total manually?

Comment: What do you mean by "alphabetizes Total in with the data"?  Also, for any one series you can manually specify a lineWidth: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.lineWidth

Comment: As @cubbuk says below, Highcharts automatically sorts the legend when the data is specified in one unit.  When I make "Total" be just another value in the data, the alphabetization puts Total in the middle of the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example from highcharts api show how you can achieve this.

> http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-linewidth-specific/

For example if you have a series like that you can change the width of the line to 5px by doing so:

```
series: [{
         data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4] , 
         lineWidth: 5
        }]
```

If you take a look at the following link you can learn what more you can do with each series object. You can easily change every attribute of series such as color, marker, linewitdth etc.. by manipulating the data object of the series or directly manipulating series object.

> http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data

Comment: Btw if you give series one by one, highcharts wont alphatize your series in the legend. The sorting will be done according to your input order.As you can see the average series is at the end of the legend as I gave that series as the last series in the options. http://jsfiddle.net/XHeMj/10/

Comment: Actually, not getting automatic sorting works better for me.  That way I can put Total first or last, and I can order based on other factors, such as low to high value.